# Python- writing sentence in given format

Tags: python

I have a file with one sentence. I let the user choose the number of 'rows' and 'columns'. I want to check how many times I can write the sentence in this kind of table without splitting words.Now I would like the text to form like this:
Input:
rows=3
columns=10
setence from file: Cat has dog.
Output:
    Cat has***
    dog. Cat**
    has dog.**

The program can't split words and in places where they can't fit place stars. Here is the part of the code I did but I feel I am not going the good direction.

My questions:
1. How can I improve my code?
2. How to make it count chars but also words?
3. General tips for this task.

My code:

```
import sys
columns, rows, path = sys.argv[1:]
columns=int(columns)
rows=int(rows)
file=open(path,"r")
text=file.read()
list=list(text.split())
length=len(list)
for i in range(length):
    k=len(lista[i])
    if k<=columns:
        print(list[i], end=" ")
    else:
        print("*")
```

Comment: write your input and expected output  properly . Your question is not clear

Comment: "The program can't split words and in places where they can't fit place stars." Sorry, I don't understand what the requirement is here

Comment: I want the program to check how many times you can write the sentence "Cat has a dog" in 'table' of given columns and rows.

Comment: It can't split words in half. And free spaces are replaced by *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was tougher than I thought it would be. There might be an easier solution out there but you can try this:

```
list_of_words = text.split()
current_character_count_for_row = 0
current_string_for_row = ""
current_row = 1
how_many_times_has_sentence_been_written = 0

is_space_available = True
# Keep going until told to stop.
while is_space_available:

    for word in list_of_words:
        # If a word is too long for a row, then return false.
        if len(word) > columns:
            is_space_available = False
            break

        # Check if we can add word to row.
        if len(word) + current_character_count_for_row < columns:
            # If at start of row, then just add word if short enough.
            if current_character_count_for_row == 0:
                current_string_for_row = current_string_for_row + word
                current_character_count_for_row += len(word)
            # otherwise, add word with a space before it.
            else:
                current_string_for_row = current_string_for_row +" " + word
                current_character_count_for_row += len(word) + 1
        # Word doesn't fit into row.
        else:

            # Fill rest of current row with *'s.
            current_string_for_row = current_string_for_row + "*"*(columns - current_character_count_for_row)

            # Print it.
            print(current_string_for_row)

            # Break if on final row.
            if current_row == rows:
                is_space_available = False
                break
            # Otherwise start a new row with the word
            current_row +=1
            current_character_count_for_row = len(word)
            current_string_for_row = word
    if current_row > rows:
        is_space_available = False
        break

    # Have got to end of words. Increment the count, unless we've gone over the row count.
    if is_space_available:
        how_many_times_has_sentence_been_written +=1




print(how_many_times_has_sentence_been_written)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I didn't expect this to be such a hard task- I was sure that maybe I don't have a good idea how to start this. I will study your code carefully but I checked and it works. Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem. I thought it would be easier too but I couldn't find a simple way of doing it. Maybe someone else will suggest a better way but either way, glad I could help.