# How to fill n tables with content of string as many times as you can?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

Basically what I would like to achieve is to have a string, let's say "Tom has a cat." and check how many times it would fill for example 10x3 table in this way, without cutting words in half:

```
"T" "o" "m" " " "h" "a" "s" " " "a" " "

"c" "a" "t" "." " " "T" "o" "m" " " " "

"h" "a" "s" " " "a" " " "c" "a" "t" "."
```

What I am currently trying to do is to have a dictionary where key is number of row, and value is a table with empty strings equal to number of columns.
What I cannot figure out is how to do something like this:

```
for i in range(1, rows+1)     #id's of keys of already created dict
        for n in range(columns):
            for letter in string:
                d["{}".format(i)][n] = letter
```

and when there is no room to finish next word it should add +1 to id and start filling next row. Then, when the sentence is complete it should keep filling from the first letter. At the end it should tell the user how many times the sentence filled the table (2 times in the example).

I hope I made it understandable, and I'm very grateful for every idea!

Edit: 
There should be a space between sentences and "." is a part of "cat.". Also in the end the program should fill all spare room with "*" like :

"c" "a" "t" "." " " "T" "o" "m" " " "*"

but it's the least important thing to do.

Comment: Is `'.'` considered part of the word `'cat.'`?

Comment: There should be a space between sentences and '.' is a part of 'cat.'. Also in the end the program should fill all spare room with '*' like 

"c" "a" "t" "." " " "T" "o" "m" " " "*"

but it's the least important thing to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python- writing sentence in given format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721576/python-writing-sentence-in-given-format)

Comment: @usr2564301 Although this question is indeed a duplicate to the question you link to, the answer to that question is quite un-Pythonic in my opinion. I'm therefore offering a cleaner solution here instead.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (probably not the cleanest) is this:

```
def into_grid(s, width, height):
    words = cycle(s.split(" "))
    res = ""
    row = 0
    col = 0
    next_word = next(words)
    while row < height:
        if col + len(next_word) <= width:
            res += next_word + " "
            col += len(next_word) + 1
            next_word = next(words)
        else:
            row += 1
            col = 0
            res += "\n"
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the sentence into words and use `itertools.cycle` to cycle through each word, and fill the list of lists according to the spare room of the current row versus the length of the current word plus a leading space if the row is not empty:

```
from itertools import cycle
def fill(sentence, rows, cols):
    table = [[]]
    words = cycle(sentence.split())
    while True:
        word = next(words)
        if len(table[-1]) + len(word) + bool(table[-1]) > cols:
            table[-1].extend('*' * (cols - len(table[-1])))
            if len(table) == rows:
                return table
            table.append([])
        if table[-1]:
            table[-1].append(' ')
        table[-1].extend(word)
```

so that:

```
fill('Tom has a cat.', 4, 10)
```

returns:

```
[['T', 'o', 'm', ' ', 'h', 'a', 's', ' ', 'a', '*'],
 ['c', 'a', 't', '.', ' ', 'T', 'o', 'm', '*', '*'],
 ['h', 'a', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'c', 'a', 't', '.'],
 ['T', 'o', 'm', ' ', 'h', 'a', 's', ' ', 'a', '*']]
```